# How to Automate watchservice , currently being called from IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have bellow code to monitor a directory for any file changes.

```
public class DirectoryWatcherExample {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        WatchService watchService
          = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

        Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));

        path.register(
          watchService, 
            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, 
              StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, 
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println(
                  "Event kind:" + event.kind() 
                    + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
            }
            key.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently this is a stand alone and is being executed from my eclipse IDE. Now I need to automate it and I should not run this class everytime. Would you please help me as to how I can remove `main()` method and run it? Can I create a exeucutable jar and run it? If i run it once then will the program continuosly listen the directlroy? When will the program stops listening the directory? Is there any time limit, I mean after a few days?